# How to install Qt to work with OpenCV and Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opencv

I am sorry if this question is already asked but, from every source I have read on google so far they don't cover the most latest versions and I am having a lot of trouble figuring this out.

I have a VS code for detecting faces and saving the ROI onto the desktop. Now, I need to add the functionality for force capture and need to employ GUI for it which openCV is not good enough for. I have been told to use Qt. For more than a week now I have been stuck at simply installing Qt and getting it to work. If anyone could help me out in-line with my project's purpose I would greatly appreciate it.

Every time I install I get some sort of different error which I am not able to understand (complete beginner here), the latest one I got was that Qt could not find the "Kit", even though the dialog box displayed the available ones (Mingw 2022).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to use both CMake and vcpkg for this.

Comment: @drescherjm could you point to some documentation where I could read more abt this accurately? Thx

Comment: Are you using VSCode or Visual Studio Community? These are completely different products with a similar name. You tag for Visual Studio Community and even titled for it but then you mention VSCode in your question.

Comment: If you are using VSCode and mingw and not Visual Studio Community with msvc you may want to install msys2 and have it install mingw and opencv. With all this said, using Qt in VSCode will not be an easy task. You may want to switch to Qt-Creator instead which will help you to achieve your goal faster.

Comment: If you don't want to switch to Qt-Creator you may look at this extension: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tonka3000.qtvsctools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tonka3000.qtvsctools) although I have not used it. I write Qt software since 2008 but I use Visual Studio Community and CMake. Qt is difficult in that you have to run moc, uic, rcs to generate code as part of your build process. Without help in VSCode that is not going to be easy. Your default tasks.json will not do that for you.

Comment: @drescherjm ty for your answers. I meant VS community itself and in the question, I meant I have written a code (program) in visual studio. Sorry for the discrepancy. So now, how do I go about it in VS community?